# How do i supress warnings in Python using notebooks on vscode?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

I'm using python notebooks for the first time in VSCode and I can't disable warnings there. I tried a lot of things such:

```
import logging
    
for name in logging.Logger.manager.loggerDict.keys():
    logging.getLogger(name).setLevel(logging.CRITICAL)
```

and:

```
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")
```

but nothing works. Can anyone help me ?